# How to allow a gender field to accept only two values?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The question: Add a gender field. Ensure the field will only
accept ‘M’ or ‘F’ and the default value should be
‘F’

PostgresSQL code:

```
alter table Patient
add Gender varchar(1)  default 'F' ,Check (Gender = 'M' or Gender = 'F');
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Check"
>  LINE 2: add Gender
> varchar(1)  default 'F' ,Check (Gender = 'M' or G...

How do i fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql: How to use ENUM datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38474575/postgresql-how-to-use-enum-datatype)

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is good, there is only a small syntax error:

```
alter table Patient
   add Gender varchar(1) default 'F',
   add Check (Gender = 'M' or Gender = 'F');
```

The second `add` was missing. Using `IN` would be typographically shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Try Below

```
CREATE TYPE gender AS ENUM ('F', 'M');

CREATE TABLE t (
    g gender default 'F' -- <==== default value
);
```